# How make object apear more round in blender?

Tags: blender

I hope you see it good on picture, as you can see this circular object isn't fully round. Is there any way I can make it look totaly smooth? [image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's a Blender stackexchange it should be posted to instead

Comment: That red outline over the mesh indicates you have marked the edges as sharp, this prevents smooth shading from blending the faces together, marking the horizontal edges as sharp is ok but you don't want every vertical edge marked as sharp.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, shading helps with this so that the corners are not as sharp looking.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19131/how-to-properly-use-face-smooth-shading

Alternatively, to make it truly more round you would have to use more quads/polygons to give the corners lower angles.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two solutions.

Solution 1 :
Look for Edge Split modifier. It will allow you to chose which edges to smooth or not, depending on the angle of the edge. In your case, you do not have apply a smooth shading on your mesh.

Solution 2 :
Look around for Subsurf modifier and Edge Crease tool.

Bonus solution 3 :
Look for Bevel modifier. Depending on your mesh, it can sometimes be the best solution.